# Setting Color of thumb icon

Tags: codenameone

I am looking to change the Color of the thumb up when I press. I can change all kinds of things but I can not seem to get just the thumb.

```
Style settingsStyle = distance.getAllStyles();
settingsStyle.setFgColor(0xff00);
settingsStyle.setBorder(null);
settingsStyle.setBgColor(0);
settingsStyle.setBgTransparency(255);



settingsStyle.setFont(distance.getUnselectedStyle().getFont().derive(13, Font.STYLE_PLAIN));
FontImage.setMaterialIcon(distance, FontImage.MATERIAL_SETTINGS);
distance.setIcon(thumb);
```

Comment: Are you referring to the slider class? I'm honestly surprised you are getting any result with this as this API was designed to set an icon on a label. You need to use `setThumbImage()` which you can create with a `FontImage` instance

Comment: What I want to do is change the color of the icon in this example    https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/MultiButton.html

Comment: Which icon? The emblem?